# can i send a message to a django template in an HttpResponseBadRequest?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Can i send an error message attached to an HttpResponseBadRequest which will be displayed in my template?
ie.

view.py

```
def myView():
....
return HttpResponseBadRequest(msg)
```

template.html

```
$.get(url,function(data){
    ...
})
.done(function(){
    ...
})
.fail(function(){
    alert(msg);
})
```

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: Did you try this? What happened?

Comment: Yes, try this. Edit the question and leave in the image what I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a global JS variable somewhere called `msg`.

If you want to refer to the data returned by the Ajax error, you need to accept it as a parameter in your fail function:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
})
```

Comment: Making this receipt in error "BAD REQUEST", but not the message that I want to send.

Comment: gracias problema resuelto!